# Как разместить окно программы по центру экрана?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-faq

Как центрировать окно программы, не зная разрешения монитора?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
QDesktopWidget desktop;
QRect rect = desktop.availableGeometry(desktop.primaryScreen()); // прямоугольник с размерами экрана
QPoint center = rect.center(); //координаты центра экрана
int x = center.x() - (window->width()/2);  // учитываем половину ширины окна
int y = center.y() - (window->height()/2); // .. половину высоты
center.setX(x);
center.setY(y);
window->move(center);
```

Answer (score 5):

Более простой способ из [Qt Wiki](https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_Center_a_Window_on_the_Screen):

```
#include <QStyle>
#include <QDesktopWidget>

window->setGeometry(
    QStyle::alignedRect(
        Qt::LeftToRight,
        Qt::AlignCenter,
        window->size(),
        qApp->desktop()->availableGeometry()
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

За окном 2019 год, новая версия `Qt 5.13.0`, и работающий код сейчас будет выглядеть так:

```
#include <QtGui>
#include <QtWidgets>
...
QDesktopWidget desktop;
QRect rect = desktop.availableGeometry(this);
QPoint center = rect.center();
int x = center.x() - (width()/2);
int y = center.y() - (height()/2);
center.setX(x);
center.setY(y);
move(center);
```